# Adding a button to order details on 'My Account' page in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

[image]

Is there a Woocommerce hook/filter to add another button besides the 'Order Again' button? I want to add this to My Account > My Orders > Order Details page.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods to add the button to your **My Account** page (make changes in any WooCommerce's pages):

1. Use WooCommerce hook/filter:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'jamy_add_button');

function jamy_add_button($order) {
    /* Your code */
    echo "Your button html code";
}
```

2. Override WooCommerce templates:

```
Copy your `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/order/order-details.php` file to `/wp-content/theme/your_theme/woocommerce/order/order-details.php`.

Then edit or add the button to the copied file as your needs.
```